# eBay API findCompletedItems replacement/work-around

Tags: ebay-api

I've been checking out the eBay API recently and was planning on using it for a project but noticed one of the key API calls I'd need ([findCompletedItems](https://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/finding/CallRef/findCompletedItems.html)) is deprecated and has been for some time. [Discussion on the eBay developer forum](https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/37466/findcompleteditems-dropped-from-finding-api.html?page=1&pageSize=10&sort=votes) from October 2020 doesn't yield much other than scraping (which eBay can and does block apparently) or paying for the MarketPlace Insights API (limited access and, based on posts from the forums, nobody can get in because eBay reviews and rejects them).

Does anyone know if it's still near impossible to access the MarketPlace Insights API or if there is another way to find completed listings from eBay through some other means? The discussion in the developer forums also brings up certain websites that are still able to show completed listings but nobody seems to understand how they do it.

Answer (score -2):

Found an API that scrapes eBay, solves captchas, and returns completed (sold) listings using keywords, aspects, categories, etc.

https://rapidapi.com/ecommet/api/ebay-average-selling-price/details